# behaviour of fread for empty (0kb) files

Tags: c, file, fread

Here is sample code which gives segmentation fault while reading empty file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[20];

    printf("1\n");
    fp = fopen("/home/amadhab/aa", "r+");
    printf("2\n");
    i = fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp);
    printf("3\n");
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
}
```

Gives o/p as

```
1
2
Segmentation fault
```

Does `fread()` fails to read an empty (0KB)file?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What should happen, if the program works, is this:

```
1
2
3
i = 0
```

When `fread()` fails, it *should* return 0 (or a number smaller than the requested number of items).  However, this does not happen.  This is probably because `fp` is null.  You are not allowed to pass a null parameter to `fread()`.  Probably, `fp` is null because `/home/amadhab/aa` does not exist.  Try using this to open the file instead:

```
#include <assert.h>

fp = fopen("/home/amadhab/aa", "r+");
assert(fp != NULL);
```

Or, for more information,

```
#include <err.h>

const char *fname = "/home/amadhab/aa";
fp = fopen(fname, "r+");
if (!fp)
    err(1, "%s", fname)
```

Note that the `err()` function is a BSD extension, but you can use `strerror()` or `perror()` on other systems if portability is a concern.

### The standard

From n1516 section 7.21.8.1:

> The `fread` function reads, into the array pointed to by `ptr`, up to `nmemb` elements whose size is specified by `size`, from the stream pointed to by `stream`.

Note that `NULL` does not point to a stream, so by passing `NULL` you are violating a precondition of the `fread()` function.  This is explicitly spelled out in section 7.1.4:

> If an argument to a [library] function has an invalid value (such as [...] a null pointer [...]) [...], the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Sir, thank you for the clarification. I have a small inked query. in section 7.19.8.1 of c99, i see nothing is  specified when `stream` is _invalid_ or NULL. Am i missing something or do i need to look somewhere else?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, you have the right place.  I'll expand the answer a little bit rather than try to cram it into a comment.

Comment: Thank you sir, but still, no mention about the behaviour of the function _if_ NULL is passed. Where do I refer to support my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28185717/2173917) below, specifically the _undefined behaviour_ part, or shall I remove that part?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Refer to appendix J, "undefined behavior".

Comment: Right. This is what I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No fread does **not** fail for empty files. [Source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fread.html#tag_03_185_04).

As already pointed out by others the error has nothing to do with the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
fp = fopen("/home/amadhab/aa", "r+");
```

there is no success check for `fopen()` return value. if `fopen()` fails, it will return NULL (which get collected in `fp`) and the subsequent usage of the variable `fp` which was used to collect the return value will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) <sup>Note</sup>. That is what is happening in

```
fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp);  // note the usage of fp here
```

causing the segmentation fault.

To avoid this, you should immediately check the return value of `fopen()` and if it fails, you should avoid accessing `fp`.

Note: Just a suggestion, learn to use a debugger [like `gdb` on linux] and step through your application. Most of the time, it *will* pinpoint the exact issue.

---

Note: Refer Annex J, `C99`, as a reason behind undefined behaviour,

> An argument to a library function has an invalid value or a type not expected by a function with variable number of arguments (7.1.4).

And, NULL is *considered* invalid value for a `FILE *` to be passed to `fread()`.

Answer (score 1):

Fread does not fail while reading the empty file. You didn't check the stream open
that is opened correctly.

```
fp = fopen("/home/amadhab/aa", "r+");
```

In this case, if the open of that file is failed. Now the fp have the value as NULL.

```
i = fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp);
```

Now you are accessing the `NULL` File Stream. This is the reason for segmentation fault. To avoid this you have to check the condition.

```
if ( ( fp = fopen("/home/amadhab/aa", "r+") ) == NULL  ){
            perror("fopen");
            exit(5);
}
```

Comment: I wojuld call `perror` then `exit` on failure of `fopen`